# tkinter: move images with background

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to move multiple images together with the background. Moving the background image works fine, but I can't figure out how to add two images on top (they disappear immediately) and then move together with the background. I guess there is an easy way to do that?

I appreciate any hint!

```
from tkinter import *
import time

tk = Tk()
w = 1000
h = 800
pos = 0
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=w, height=h)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

background_image = PhotoImage(file="bg.gif")
background_label = Label(tk, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0)
tk.update()

def addImages(files):
    for f in files:
        image = PhotoImage(file=f)
        label = Label(tk, image=image)
        label.place(x=files[f][0],y=files[f][1])
    tk.update()

def move(xPos):
    pos = background_label.winfo_x() - xPos
    while background_label.winfo_x() > pos:
        background_label.place(x=background_label.winfo_x()-25)
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.001)

img = {"file1.gif": [10,10], "file2.gif": [50,50]}
addImages(img)
move(100)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having difficulty in understanding your code. Why create a canvas and then not use it? You have also littered your code with `tk.update()`, most of which are unnecessary. But, the described problem is because you create the labels inside a function and the association between label and image gets garbage collected when the function exits. You have to explicitly remember this association:

```
def addImages(files):
    for f in files:
        image = PhotoImage(file=f)
        label = Label(tk, image=image)
        label.image = image    # Lets the label remember the image outside the function
        label.place(x=files[f][0],y=files[f][1])
```

If you are then going to move these labels you might want to keep some kind of reference to them or you won't be able to address them.

**Complete example**

I changed `tk` to `root` because `tk` is the name usually used as alias for tkinter (eg. `import tkinter as tk`) which gets confusing.

I'm creating a `image_list` to hold references to the labels containing images. Later I use the list to loop through the labels and move them.

After I have built the GUI I wait 1000 milliseconds before starting the `move` function. Also I move the images just 1 pixel at a time to clearer see the action.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')  # Setting window size instead of usin canvas to do that
pos = 0

background_image = PhotoImage(file="bg.gif")
background_label = Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0)

image_list = []     # List for holding references to labels with images
def addImages(files):
    for f in files:
        image = PhotoImage(file=f)
        label = Label(root, image=image)
        label.image = image    # Remember the image outside the function
        label.place(x=files[f][0],y=files[f][1])
        image_list.append(label)    # Append created Label to the list

def move(xPos):
    pos = background_label.winfo_x() - xPos
    while background_label.winfo_x() > pos:
        background_label.place(x=background_label.winfo_x()-1)
        for image in image_list:    # Loop over labels in list
            image.place(x=image.winfo_x()-1)    # Move the label
        root.update()
        time.sleep(0.001)

img = {"file1.gif": [10,10], "file2.gif": [50,50]}
addImages(img)
root.after(1000, move, 100) # Waits 1 second and then moves images

root.mainloop()
```

By the way; `after` is a function much preferred over `sleep` as sleep suspends the program until its finished, whereas after works by making a call after a time and the program runs meanwhile. But if you are ok with that the program freezes during the move, then why not.

Comment: Thx! Keeping some kind of reference is what I'm struggling with. I don't know how to address all the labels to move. I have to call them individually?

Comment: Added complete example with saving references and all.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure why using a list didn't work for me before, but your code worked just fine. I guess it has something to do with using the geometry method.

Comment: Not really. It works the same with canvas. But it seemed a bit complicated way to set a size.